# MUI datagrid pagination is not synced with filter

Tags: typescript, mui-x

when I try to filter anything on the column of datagrid, after filter is applied there is only one results found but still pagination is rendering with all pages to display in the table.

one result is found after filter but pagination is there, we can able to move to next page, but this shouldn't happen when one result is there, pagination should be disabled.

**Demo** - https://stackblitz.com/run?file=demo.tsx
This is the sample code taken from the official [MUI](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/pagination/#server-side-pagination) documentation.

[Attached image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zubMU.png)

[can be able to move to next page as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM8x2.png)